# Iterrows performance

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm working on python 2.7, pandas ( version 0.18.1 ) data frames.
I have to modify a column in the data frame based on several columns in the same data frame.

For that I have written my code as below
Sample data is like below

`data` is my dataframe

My sample data is like

```
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
| a | b | c  | d  | e |    f    | g | h  | i  | j | discount |
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 65497.6 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 73882.8 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 88588   |   | 22 |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 106480  |   | 20 | 10 |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 52500   |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   | 20 | 10 |   | 22997.5 |   |    |    |   |        0 |
|   |   |    |    |   |         |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    | 20 |   | 0       |   |    |    |   |        0 |
| 0 |   |    |    |   | 10520   |   |    |    |   |        0 |
+---+---+----+----+---+---------+---+----+----+---+----------+
```

And my code is like below

```
columns1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
columns2 = ['f','g','h','i','j']
data['discount'] = 0
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for col1 in columns1 :
      value = row[col1]
      if value > 0:
         a = value
         break;
    for col2 in columns2 :
      value = row[col2]
      if value > 0:
         b = value
         break;
    if( a != 0 and b != 0):
        data.loc[i, 'discount'] = abs(a-b)
```

As I'm doing this way it is taking lot of time and lot of memory on the large dataset. I have 700MB of data, It is taking more than 120GB of RAM to process and approximately after 10 hours process is giving the exception saying `Memory Error`

according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316, I should not use like that, Please let me know how can I write this code more efficient.

**Please let me know the reason for down voting my question, so that I can learn**

Comment: please provide a sample of the data so we can experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your empty cells are `NaN` values, this gives you the first non-NA value of each row for the group of columns you are interested in:

```
df[df>0][columns1].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    20.0
6     NaN
7    20.0
8     NaN
```

Thus, this will give you the `abs(a-b)` you're searching for:

```
res = (df[df>0][columns1].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
      -df[df>0][columns2].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]).abs()
res

0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5    22977.5
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
```

You can either combine it with your initialized `discount` column:

```
res.combine_first(df.discount)
```

or fill the blanks:

```
res.fillna(0)
```